# Javascript basic calculations always get NaN

Tags: javascript

Hello i am doing a basic calculator for a game but I am facing a problem I just started to learn this programming language read all tutorials I found and now I am just making some code and getting some experience , so I write a calculation code that I was written in a php before in a php was working perfect but I was using different technique there , so in javascript I create a function which will be called ones the calculate button will be pressed and create an object to store all data of 5 players take a look :

```
function count(){

    function ninjas (name,dmg,dmgrate,dmggrow,speed,fury) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dmg = dmg;
        this.dmgrate = dmgrate;
        this.dmggrow = dmggrow;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.fury = fury;
    }
    var name = [];
    var dmg = [];
    var dmgrate = [];
    var dmggrow = [];
    var speed = [];
    var fury = [];
    var ninja = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <5; i++){
      name[name.length] = document.getElementById("ninja" + (i +1)).value;
        dmg[dmg.length] = document.getElementById("dmg" + (i +1)).value; 
      dmgrate[dmgrate.length] = document.getElementById("dmgrate" + (i +1)).value; 
        dmggrow[dmggrow.length] = document.getElementById("dmggrow" + (i +1)).value; 
        speed[speed.length] = document.getElementById("speed" + (i +1)).value; 
        fury[fury.length] = 50;
        ninja[i] = new ninjas(name[i],dmg[i],dmgrate[i],dmggrow[i],speed[i],fury[i]);
    }

    ninja.sort(function(a, b){return b.speed - a.speed}); 

    var totaldmg;
    var damagerate;
    var damagegrow; 
    var furydmg;

    for(var a = 0; a < 6; a++){ // 6 fight 
        for(var b = 0; b < 5; b++){ // 5 ninjas
            if(ninja[b].name == "Kabuto"){
                 if(ninja[b].fury == 100){
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    damagegrow = damagerate / 100 * ninja[b].dmggrow;
                    furydmg = damagegrow + (damagegrow / 100) * ((ninja[b].fury - 100) / 0.25);
                    totaldmg += furydmg;
                    for(var c = 0; c < 5; c++){ // add fury each ninja by 25
                        ninja[c].fury +=25;
                    }
                     ninja[b].fury -= 25;
                     ninja[b].fury +=100;
                 }else if(ninja[b].fury > 100){
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    damagegrow = damagerate / 100 * ninja[b].dmggrow;
                    totaldmg += damagegrow;
                    for(var c = 0; c < 5; c++){// add fury each ninja by 25
                        ninja[c].fury +=25;
                    }
                     ninja[b].fury -= 25;
                     ninja[b].fury +=100;
                 }else {
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    totaldmg += damagerate;
                    ninja[b].fury += 50;
                 }
            } else {
                if(ninja[b].fury == 100){
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    damagegrow = damagerate / 100 * ninja[b].dmggrow;
                    totaldmg += damagegrow;
                    ninja[b].fury = 0;
                }else if(ninja[b].fury > 100){
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    damagegrow = damagerate / 100 * ninja[b].dmggrow;
                    furydmg = damagegrow + (damagegrow / 100) * ((ninja[b].fury - 100) / 0.25);
                    totaldmg += furydmg;
                    ninja[b].fury = 0;
                }else {
                    damagerate = ninja[b].dmg / 100 * ninja[b].dmgrate;
                    totaldmg += damagerate;
                    ninja[b].fury += 50;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totaldmg;
};
```

I used few loops to store all data in her places and then use short function to short everyone by speed attribute after each step I did a check if everything is alright but at the end somehow I still got result which is NaN could someone help me to solve this I have checked my code many times but could find where is mistake , maybe there is something I do not know about a javascript and missed

Comment: try to compact your problem into a [mcve] it'll not only allow us to help you, but it'll also enforce your understanding of where the problem is coming from

Comment: You're performing math on strings.

Comment: [Welcome to JavaScript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: It's a Chinese copy of calculator I assume, get a refund. and what Nathan K said would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize your total variables to 0

this way totaldmg += value will not result in totaldmg = "undefined + value;

```
var totaldmg = 0;
var damagerate = 0;
var damagegrow = 0; 
var furydmg = 0;
```

Also, when reading the values from the DOM, convert them to numerics as string literals will concatenate

```
for(var i = 0; i <5; i++){
  name[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("ninja" + (i +1)).value, 10);
  dmg[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("dmg" + (i +1)).value, 10); 
  dmgrate[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("dmgrate" + (i +1)).value, 10); 
  dmggrow[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("dmggrow" + (i +1)).value, 10); 
  speed[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("speed" + (i +1)).value, 10); 
  fury[i] = 50;
  ninja[i] = new ninjas(name[i],dmg[i],dmgrate[i],dmggrow[i],speed[i],fury[i]);
}
```

Comment: okay so i do not sure if i have to set 0 on those variables but ones i check typeof values from DOM they was a string so i used parseInt to convert them to a number and now its works fine tnx u for explaining

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do and how the code is supposed to work, but from just looking at your code here is the first error I could identify:

```
name[name.length]
dmg[dmg.length]
dmgrate[dmgrate.length]
speed[speed.length]
//etc
```

This is wrong. The elements in an array start from `0` and end to `array.length - 1`. This means that `name[name.length]` doesn't exist.

Here are some links on how a javascript array works:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

I hope this helps you. I will continue to see your code and if I find any other errors I am going to add them to my answer

2) How is this supposed to work:

```
for(var i = 0; i <5; i++){
    name[name.length] = document.getElementById("ninja" + (i +1)).value;
    dmg[dmg.length] = document.getElementById("dmg" + (i +1)).value; 
    dmgrate[dmgrate.length] = document.getElementById("dmgrate" + (i +1)).value; 
    dmggrow[dmggrow.length] = document.getElementById("dmggrow" + (i +1)).value; 
    speed[speed.length] = document.getElementById("speed" + (i +1)).value; 
    fury[fury.length] = 50;
    //...
}
```

If you are trying to add elements to an array in javascript, `name[name.length]` is not the way it can be done. At the links above you can see how to do it, using the `array.push(arg);` function.

Comment: u are wrong there is many ways to push array , and i know almost all of them i chose this wai because i think its fits me better